# MS SQL вставить значение на 1 больше последнего

Tags: sql, sql-server

Вопрос освещен в заголовке, нужно сделать запрос такого типа:

```
insert into Table (date, doc_number, type)
values (
   '01.01.2017',
   "тут номер последнего документа + 1",
   'type1'
);
```

Comment: Если это id, то чем вам auto_increment не угодил?

Comment: не хотел писать всю структуру, это для примера.

Comment: В MS SQL даже два способа правильного назначения ID. Один - это identity поля, которые получают следующее значение (с оговорками) автоматически и второй - это sequence. Так зачем при всех этих встроенных средствах нужно использовать потенциально не безопасный метод, который будет блокировать таблицу или глючить при параллельной работе нескольких запросов. А что касается last_value это оконная функция и тут вообще работать не может. можно в виде `insert into Table select max(ID)+1 from Table`, но повторюсь _не делайте так_, опишите задачу, в 95% случаев такие задачи решаются по другому

Comment: Спасибо, я немного переделал задание, поле doc_number ключевое, но не должно быть автоинкрементировано. Просто сейчас нужно написать такой insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into Table (date, doc_number, type)
 select '01.01.2017',coalesce(max(doc_number),0)+1,'type1'
   from Table
```

Но вот правильный ли это подход, решать вам. Если последний документ удалили, то стоит ли например давать освободившийся номер следующему документу. Возможно `sequence` было бы лучшим решением данной задачи.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into Table (date, doc_number, type)
values (
   '01.01.2017',
   (select max(doc_number)+1 from Table),
   'type1'
);
```